# What are TVB 3.2

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Want to know what are `TVB 3.2` XML standards? Also does anybody have the `XSD` file for the same.

I have tried to search this xsd or related information but could not find any.

Comment: Do you have any context? TVB doesn't strike me as a widely known acronym.

Answer (score 0):

These are the Television Bureau of Advertising standards for electronic orders, etc. used for conducting business between advertisers / advertising agencies and TV stations / local station rep firms.

Comment: Can you please include links for your sources? Also, I'm not sure this answers the questions

Comment: Answer is correct. I also need an XSD/DTD, all I find via google is announcements about the standard coming into existence.